# Hide language WPML

Tags: php, wordpress, wpml

I am using **WPML** language, and cant find solution for next thing:

On the Language switcher i want to hide language, lets say for example - "he", if current language is lets say for example "ar", so when we on arabic site we will not see on the selector the Hebrew, and same thing if we on Hebrew, the arabic will not display.

On shorten words: what i want is - if we on arabic site - the hebrew flag will be hidden.

What i tried:

```
function language_selector_flags(){
    $languages = icl_get_languages('skip_missing=0');
    if(!empty($languages)){
       if(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='en') 
       {
$order = array('ar'); //Specify your sort order here
       }
elseif(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='he')
{
$order = array('en', 'ar'); //Specify your sort order here
}

        foreach ($order as $l) {
            if (isset($languages[$l])) {
                $l = $languages[$l]; //grab this language from the unsorted array that is returned by icl_get_languages()

                //Display whatever way you want -- I'm just displaying flags in anchors  (CSS: a {float:left; display:block;width:18px;height:12px;margin:0 2px;overflow:hidden;line-height:100px;})
                if($l['active']) { $class = "active"; $url=""; } else { $class = ''; $url = 'href="'.$l['url'].'"'; }
                echo '<a '.$url.' style="background:url('.$l['country_flag_url'].') no-repeat;" class="flag '.$class.'">';
                echo $l['language_code'].'';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Its not affect at all the selector.

Comment: so you only want the current language/flag to be shown?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function language_selector_flags(){
    $languages = icl_get_languages('skip_missing=0');
    if(!empty($languages)){
        $filter = array();
        $filter['ar'] = array( 'he' );
        // set your other filters here

        $active_language = null;
        foreach ($languages as $l)
            if($l['active']) {
                $active_language = $l['language_code'];
                break;
            }

        $filter = $active_language && isset( $filter[$active_language] ) ? $filter[$active_language] : array();
        foreach ($languages as $l) {

                //Display whatever way you want -- I'm just displaying flags in anchors  (CSS: a {float:left; display:block;width:18px;height:12px;margin:0 2px;overflow:hidden;line-height:100px;})
                if( in_array( $l['language_code'], $filter) )
                    continue;
                if($l['active']) { $class = "active"; $url=""; } else { $class = ''; $url = 'href="'.$l['url'].'"'; }
                echo '<a '.$url.' class="flag '.$class.'"><img src="', $l['country_flag_url'], '" alt="', esc_attr( $l['language_code'] ), '" /></a>';
            }
        }
    }
```

EDIT: If I get this right, your client(I assume) doesn't want his customers (Israelis especiay) to know that he offer service also to the arabic speaking cusomers. If it so then you can parse the `Accept-Language` header and filter the language selector according the result.

Comment: My client dont want arabic to see israel language button... you got the idea.

Comment: mmm its start to look like my client want, except the error and how the flags looks like: http://www.hotel7777.com/?lang=ar

Comment: Now i removed the error, but still i see the name of the lang, on the flag.. how can i fix that?

Comment: You can see it on the footer

Comment: I did edit the code in my answer to change lang name to lang flag.

Answer (score 6):

You can check out the plugin *[WPML Flag In Menu](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wpml-flag-in-menu/)*.

You could use the `plugin_wpml_flag_in_menu()` function from the plugin ([see source code here](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/wpml-flag-in-menu/trunk/wpml_flag_in_menu.php)) and replace:

```
// Exclude current viewing language             
if( $l['language_code'] != ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE )
{
    // ...
}
```

with

```
// Include only the current language                
if( $l['language_code'] == ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE )
{
    // ...
}
```

to show only the current language/flag, if I understand you correctly.

**ps:** If you need further assistance, you could for exampe show us the output of this debug function for the active language:

```
function debug_icl_active_language()
{
    $languages = icl_get_languages( 'skip_missing=0' );
    foreach( (array) $languages as $l )
    {
        if( $l['active'] )
        { 
            printf( '<pre> Total languages: %d - Active: %s </pre>', 
                    count( $languages ), 
                    print_r( $l, TRUE ) );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, i want to up this question... what i get now is the current flag is not shown up... what i want is - if we on arabic site - the hebrew flag will be hidden  http://www.hotel7777.com/

Comment: @Bside You can try to debug with the `debug_icl_active_language()` function

Comment: Can you share the result from the debug function?

Answer (score 4):

i have some useful link for you, please go through it first:

http://wpml.org/forums/topic/hide-language-vs-display-hidden-languages-in-your-profile-not-working/

http://wpml.org/forums/topic/hide-one-language/

http://wpml.org/forums/topic/hiding-active-language-in-menu/

http://wpml.org/forums/topic/language-selector-how-to-hide-one-language/

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem/issue:

On this website: https://neu.member-diving.com/

I have languages I not need in the switcher. I tried the code above, but it nothing changed so far.

So, what I would like to do is, When a client is on the one "german" page, the other german languages in the switcher should not need to be there, only the english one and the actual german one.

Where do I need to put code like

```
function language_selector_flags(){
    $languages = icl_get_languages('skip_missing=0');
    if(!empty($languages)){
        $filter = array();
        $filter['ar'] = array( 'he' );
        // set your other filters here

        $active_language = null;
        foreach ($languages as $l)
            if($l['active']) {
                $active_language = $l['language_code'];
                break;
            }

        $filter = $active_language && isset( $filter[$active_language] ) ? $filter[$active_language] : array();
        foreach ($languages as $l) {

                //Display whatever way you want -- I'm just displaying flags in anchors  (CSS: a {float:left; display:block;width:18px;height:12px;margin:0 2px;overflow:hidden;line-height:100px;})
                if( in_array( $l['language_code'], $filter) )
                    continue;
                if($l['active']) { $class = "active"; $url=""; } else { $class = ''; $url = 'href="'.$l['url'].'"'; }
                echo '<a '.$url.' class="flag '.$class.'"><img src="', $l['country_flag_url'], '" alt="', esc_attr( $l['language_code'] ), '" /></a>';
            }
        }
    }
```